# onDrag function not working when i m setting state using this plugin react-google-maps in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-maps

**onDrag()** function not working when I m setting state using this plugin react-google-maps in react js

in `GoogleMapComponentWithMarker.js(chield component)`

```
    <GoogleMap
    ref={ map => !props.isSetMapRef && props.setMapRef(map && map) }
    defaultZoom={props.markerData.length !== 0 ? 13 : 5}
    defaultCenter={{
      lat: parseFloat(props.markerLat),
      lng: parseFloat(props.markerLang),
    }}
    center={{
      lat: parseFloat(props.markerLat),
      lng: parseFloat(props.markerLang),
    }}    
    **onDrag={() => props.setCenterLatLong(props.mapRef.getCenter().toJSON())}**
  >

        <Marker
          key={marker.key}
          icon={{
            url: props.selectedMarkerKey === marker.key ? MAP_PIN_3 : MAP_PIN_2,
          }}
          position={{
            lat: parseFloat(marker.markerLatitude),
            lng: parseFloat(marker.markerLongitude), // longitude to position the marker
          }}
          onClick={(message) => {
            const lat = message.latLng.lat();
            const lang = message.latLng.lng();
            props.handleMarkerClick(marker.markerName, lang, lat, marker.key);
          }}
          title={marker.markerName}
          // Get the data that will be used for InfoWindow.
        >        
            <InfoWindow
              position={{
                lat: props.markerLat,
                lng: props.markerLang,
              }}
              onCloseClick={() => props.handleInfoboxClick()}
            >
              <div>
                <h4>{props.infoboxMessage}</h4>
              </div>
            </InfoWindow>          
        </Marker>
  </GoogleMap>
```

In GoogleMap.js (parent component)

```
<GoogleMapComponentWithMarker
    setCenterLatLong = {this.setCenterLatLong}
  />
```

here is method in same file

```
    setCenterLatLong = (centerLatLongData) => {
    console.log(centerLatLongData);
    **this.setState({
      panCenterLatitude: centerLatLongData.lat,
      panCenterLongitude: centerLatLongData.lng,
      onPanSearchRadios: 5,
      isSearchInThisAreaEnabled: true,
    });**
  }
```

when I make comment this setState block then onDrag working fine else map is not draggable map remains at same position.

Do we have any callback function after drag ? so we can set state after callback of onDrag and default functionality would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this `onDragend`

there are two events
`google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragstart', function() { alert('map dragged'); } );
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() { alert('map dragged'); } );`

so, you will detect when the drag event was finished

Comment: Already tried onDragEnd, the same behaviour is there I can not pan map if there is setState block Also it is working fine if I comment that setState block.